# Magento 2: Event name before place order?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, custom, magento2.1.5

I'm looking for event before any order placed. Need to do validation on observer.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

If there is Bank Transfer then before clicked on "Place Order", If there is Paypal then Before went to Paypal.

Before it redirects to any third party Online/Offline it should be called.

I'm here `<site url>checkout/#payment`

Comment: do you get to know anything?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this event `sales_order_place_before` to run callback before customer placing order.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_before">
        <observer name="unique_identifier" instance="ModuleName\ClassObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```